# Publishing PostGIS-Raster Using Mapserver

Tags: postgis, mapserver

I have a problem with the rasters stored in my Database or with mapserver publishing those. Rasters contain 4 bands and i want to create RGB and FCI-color-composits.

When I add the table they are coming from (partition of big table) to qgis, i get the first image below, everything seems fine. When i use mapserver to publish the rasterdata i get really bad results.

Here is my mapfile layer definition:

```
LAYER
    NAME sentinel_2rgb
    TYPE raster
    STATUS ON
    VALIDATION
        "table" "s2_20[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]"
    END
    DATA "PG:host=host port=5432 dbname=dbname user=user password=pw table=%table% column=rast mode=2"
    PROCESSING "SCALE=AUTO"
    PROCESSING "BANDS=3,2,1"
    METADATA
        wms_title "sentinel_2rgb"
        wms_abstract "abs"
        wms_srs "EPSG:25832"
        wms_extend "-1877994.66 3932281.56 836715.13 9440581.95" # https://epsg.io/25832 projected bounds
    END
END
```

[image: Direct From DB]

[image: Using Mapserver]